# Some keys not working properly in Lenovo G500

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop-repair, lenovo-laptop

I use Lenovo G500 laptop which runs on Windows 8. It has a problem.

1. Some keys that should be used along with Shift key is working not properly, its output is not correct. I will explain it. When I press 'Shift+2' it should show '@', but instead it is showing ". Also Shift+' should show ", but it is showing @. Also when Shift+3 gives me '£', instead of '#'. The back slash(not '/', its reverse slash) key is giving '#'. If want to put '\', I had to press Alt+.

Why this happens ? How can I fix this ?

Comment: You're turning the flight mode on or off? For the second question, check the keyboard input. Change it to US keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem with my lenovo G500 Laptop. actually the keyboard and keys are functioning properly but,the problem is Printing mistake of letters on keys. they misplaced the keys @,",|,~,#,\, and the euro symbol. to fix this the only option is changing the keys.

Answer (score 2):

Try updating the BIOS to see if it helps.

We have had similar problems at work with one of the notebooks (wrong reactions to the number keys), and after updating the BIOS they start working properly.

There might also be a hot-fix available on Lenovo's support page.

Comment: Updating the BIOS is seldom recommended as a solution to anything. Can you update your answer to suggest why you think it will help here. Include if you have had a similar issue and solved it this way. Thanks.

Comment: Wireless on/off switches are typically controlled or involved with ACPI, which is part of the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

In my case with Lenovo G500 , i set the keyboard language on UK English and works perfectly.